# Naming guidelines for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any guidelines online for idiomatic name capitalization in Node.js? (I am specifically interested in capitalization of "ID" in this instance).

Comment: There are a couple of different code styles, best one I've seen so far is this: `snake_case` for variables, `Snake_Case` for classes, `UPPER_CASE` for constants.

Comment: In idiomatic Node, `id` should be completely lowercased. When it forms part of an identifier, such as `userId`, camelcasing becomes obvious. Convention holds that constructor functions should be upper camelcased, i.e. `UserModel` and constants in screaming snake case, i.e. `THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are *usually* Capitalized, everything else is *usually* camelCased.

Answer (score -2):

The Node.js source code contains the following line:

`function getEncodingId(encoding) {`

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L680

This provides an example of the casing of "ID" from the source code of Node.js itself (a somewhat authoritative source)

Comment: I'm just passing through, but how does this answer your own question?

Comment: This provides an example of the casing of "ID" from the source code of Node.js itself (a somewhat authoritative source).